# Micronaut environments and logback profiles

Tags: logback, environment, profile, micronaut

How to write  logback.xml for Micronaut, like Spring Boot:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/profile-logback-logging-config.html

I think springProfile doesn't exist in Micronaut.
I have Micronaut environments and I want to use these for example change logging format only per Micronaut environment.

Best regards
Imre

Comment: I'm looking for solution for that part:
<springProfile name="dev">
...
</springProfile>

Comment: Project is here: https://github.com/setmy-info/micronaut-start-project/tree/develop

Comment: This is duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135912/micronaut-configure-logger-appenders-based-of-the-enviroment

Answer (score -7, accepted):

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/blob/master/websocket-chat/src/main/resources/logback.xml

Recently, I ported my spring boot application to Micronaut and used the same logback.xml as given above. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi.

I got similar solution. But I don't see there what I'm looking for.
I'm trying to point to section in the link, I added:
<springProfile name="dev">
...
</springProfile>

With tag property "name" I can bind section to spring profile (usually used for environment separation).
In Micronaut we have environment's. So how can I bind section of configuration to Micronaut environments?

Comment: So I have a gradle micronaut project and there's a build.gradle file which has the below configuration to run the dev profile: `configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly 
}`  `run.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly`                                                 `run.jvmArgs('-Dmicronaut.environments=dev','-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')`

Comment: I can say, that environments are working in my Micronaut project perfectly. I can choose with build tool (for may case maven) Micronaut environment. Problem is how can one **Micronaut environment** have section in logback? From suggestion I don't see that logback does something different with dev environment.

Comment: The provided answer doesnt show an example on how to use micronaut environments as profiles.  I believe the OP is trying to do something like this using micronaut 

`<springProfile name="dev">
   <syslogHost>some-host</syslogHost>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="prod">
   <syslogHost>some-host</syslogHost>
  </springProfile>`

Comment: @salazarin Is there any other way to do the operation without changing anything in build.gradle?. Can we achieve the same by doing some changes in IntelliJ IDE